# How can I play an audio with Ionic 6 and Vue.js 3?

Tags: vue.js, cordova, capacitor, ionic6

I'm a bit lost here and I need some guidance.

I'm trying to play an audio file in a Ionic 6 with Vue.js 3 in a browser...

I installed Native Audio (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio)

When I tried to play the audio I get

> Native: tried calling NativeAudio.preloadSimple, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

and after that an error:

> cordova_not_available

I checked that error out about requiring to install a browser...

```
 ionic cordova platform add browser
```

I get this error...

> [ERROR] Ionic doesn't support using Cordova with @ionic/vue projects.

I've noticed this version of ionic comes with capacitor 4.*
I've been doing some research and the module I found uses capacitor 3...

Any ideas or advice? Thanks!

Comment: isn't using an audio tag and the play api of the browser possibly a solution? also check if the cordova.js is included in the index file.

Comment: For the time being, I'm using the <audio> BUT, I'm not sure it will work if I try to generate  it as an android app... Also, apparently Cordova is no longer supported in the latter versions so there must be a way to do it with capacitor, but I could not find anything for capacitor 4.0 and above

Comment: I've tried the <audio> tag approach successfully before (for an android app using cordova). It's very likely to work all right with capacitor too. good luck.

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks! Ill keep the post updated with the results...